# Python watchdog finishes in a neverending loop because of file action on file it monitors

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I'm writing a python script that uses watchdog to monitor a directory and performs an action on a file that just got modified.
My problem is that the action the script performs on the file refills watchdog's event list with the same file so the script goes into an inifinite loop.

Anyway to monitor modified files, and perform an action on them without that action triggering watchdog again ?

```
   import os
   import watchdog.events
   import watchdog.observers    


    class OsyncStateHandler(watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    """Writes state files"""

    def __init__(self, replica):
            self.replica = replica
            ignore = list()
            ignore.append(self.replica.path + self.replica.osync_dir + "*")
            watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, ignore_patterns=ignore)
            self.move_file_handler = open(replica.moved_list_file, 'a')

    def __del__(self):
            self.del_file_handler.close()

    def on_modified(self, event):
            print(event.event_type)
            print(event.key)
            if (event.src_path == self.replica.path):
                    return
            # Fix for Rsync: update mtime with ctime so rsync will aknowldge attr changes (chmod / setfacl only change ctime)
            if (currentConfig['RSYNC_OPTIONS']['sync_attrs'].lower() == "yes"):
                    update_mtime_with_ctime(event.src_path)
            self.mod_file_handler.write(event.src_path + '\n')
            self.mod_file_handler.flush()
            self.replica.increaseOss()


    INITREPLICA = Replica(INITIATOR_TYPE, currentConfig['REPLICAS'][INITIATOR_TYPE])
    fs_event_handler = OsyncStateHandler(INITREPLICA)
    fs_observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
    fs_observer.schedule(fs_event_handler, INITREPLICA.path, recursive=True)

    fs_observer.start()
    try:
            while True:
                    time.sleep(2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            fs_observer.stop()
    fs_observer.join()
```

I thought pausing the observer would be an idea to execute my mtime update function, but then other files copied to the directory might not be monitored while this happens.

Is there anyway to get watchdog discard this function action on filesystem ? Or maybe tell watchdog to discard every action done by the script itself ?

Regards,
Ozy.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found a nasty but working solution. Keep the file that just was modified in a list, and if next event corresponds to that file, remove it from the list but don't proceed it.

```
    def __init__(self, replica):
            self.replica = replica
            self.ignore = list()
            self.ignore.append(self.replica.path + self.replica.osync_dir + "*")
            self.ignoreevents = list()
            watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, ignore_patterns=se$
            self.mod_file_handler = open(replica.modded_list_file, 'a')

    def __del__(self):
            self.del_file_handler.close()

    def on_modified(self, event):
            print(event.event_type)
            print(event.key)
            if (event.src_path == self.replica.path):
                    return
            if (event.src_path in self.ignoreevents):
                    self.ignoreevents.remove(event.src_path)
                    return

            # Fix for Rsync: update mtime with ctime so rsync will aknowldge attr changes$
            if (CONFIG['RSYNC_OPTIONS']['sync_attrs'].lower() == "yes"):
                    # Precision of ctime only works in Python 3+
                    ctime = os.path.getctime(event.src_path)
                    os.utime(event.src_path, (ctime, ctime))
                    self.ignoreevents.append(event.src_path)
            self.mod_file_handler.write(event.src_path + '\n')
            self.mod_file_handler.flush()
            self.replica.increaseOss()
```